# How to pass props from URL in vueJS when redirect in vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

My '/' path redirect to '/loading' and I need to pass props like mysite/?demo=true and then that prop pass to the component attached to '/loading'

this is the router config

```
{
  path: '/',
  redirect: '/loading',
},
{
  path: '/loading',
  component: Loading
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: { path: '/loading', params: { default: true, demo: true } }
    },
    {
      path: '/loading',
      component: Loading
    },
```

And in your Loading component, you define a prop called demo, like:

```
props: {
  demo: Boolean,
}
```

Then you will be able to access `this.demo` and read true, wich is the value passed via route.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on Mathew's solution,  to access the route parameter,  you could do `this.$route.params.demo`